# Firebase Push notification not receiving on Android 12

Tags: android, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, pixel, android-12

My Xamarin.Android app's push notification only works on Android 11 (Pixel 3 XL). Currently my app targets Android 11, however it also runs on Android 12 (Pixel 6 Pro). The only thing that is not working is Firebase push notifications. Below is the code that I am using. For the past week I have been researching the issue and saw posts about a specific issue with Android 12 (Pixel 6) not recieving push notifications. I performed changes to the phone configurations that others suggested and another app notification began to work, yet mine still has not. Any ideas would help.Thanks.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
            {
                // Notification channels are new in API 26 (and not a part of the
                // support library). There is no need to create a notification
                // channel on older versions of Android.


                var name = "NameOfChannel";
                var description = "Notification Channel";
                var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationImportance.Max)
                {
                    Description = description
                };

                var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
                notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);

            }
```

Comment: I am not sure what issue are you facing do you get an exception or is the notification not showing up......

Comment: @FreakyAli when I send a test messge from firebase console to both Pixel 3 and Pixel 6 phones at the same time, only the Pixel 3 Android 11 recieved the message. There is not error that shows up on my logs for the Pixel 6 Android 12 phone. I have checked my code and FCM Token to make sure it is correct. Still nothing. Thanks.

Comment: Did you apply a breakpoint and check if you are receiving it at all?

Comment: As i know, Android 12 has some special on Network. You could get further help in the link  below. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. Which was to add **android:exported="false"** on the Firebase service tag within the AndroidManifest.

Comment: What is the Firebase service tag?  I'm not seeing anything like that in my AndroidManifest file and I'm having the same issue where Android 12 devices aren't getting push notifications

Comment: I already added exported="false" to FirebaseMessageService service but still hasn't received any notifications.

Comment: what does changing to false do?

Answer (score 5):

What I was missed is

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
```

If Notification has pendingIntent then set mutable/immutable Flag to it

Answer (score 3):

```
               PendingIntent pendingIntent;
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.S)
                {
                pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,notificationId,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
                }
                else
                {
                pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(context,notificationId,notificationIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                }
                builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```