# Xamarin Push Notification Firebase Android 12 (exported)

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, push-notification

i would like to implement the GettingStarted from the Package [Github](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/PushNotificationPlugin/blob/master/docs/GettingStarted.md).
So far so good if i do everything like in the Tutorial im getting the Error "Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]" for the crc640921eac73192168e.PNMessagingService. That means i have to add Code to the Manifest.xml with the property exported=true or false. But i cant figure out which Code i have to paste in the XML to make it work properly? In a furhter Question from another User [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71013083/firebase-push-notification-not-receiving-on-android-12) he got the answer for setting exported = false but he dont said which the exact code has to be, maybe so can help me :D

Answer (score 8):

For those who are still having this issue (which I am having hard time to search the answer), actually this issue is easily solved by adding Exported = false on Tag (It could be in Service, Activity etc.)

Example:

```
[Service (Exported=false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
   or
[Activity (Exported=false)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable }]
```

For adding it into Android Manifest (just need either one, the above or below)

```
<service
android:name="crc64620eeeaa876b9f26.MessagingServiceHandler" 
android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />   
    </intent-filter>
```

Hope this help!
Reinhard Sual

Comment: It works when added 'android:exported="false"' in Activity tags itself. No need to add in main Android Manifest file. If everything okay after build, automatically added in Android Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Put the this into receiver of the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. This is the Receiver of this plugin. You need to put this inside the `<application>` tag.

```
<receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
    <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

For more details, you could check the `AndroidManifest.xml` of the sample for this plugin.

Comment: Hello, i have already done that before :D but im still getting the same error. Is it maybe a bug in VS 2022?

Comment: Schweregrad Code Beschreibung Projekt Datei Zeile Unterdrückungszustand
Fehler  ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1225665538.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #46): crc640921eac73192168e.PNMessagingService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

Comment: Have you download the sample code for the this plugin? Did you get the same error?

Comment: Downloaded the Sample, and also getting the Error:
ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl1405017622.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #35): crc640921eac73192168e.PNMessagingService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]